# logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler not working

Tags: python, logging

The following code has worked for me before and should work according to documentation:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging.handlers
>>> logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler("log.log")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WatchedFileHandler'
```

From the docs:

```
 class logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(filename[, mode[, encoding[, delay]]])
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Okay, so it turns out, that for some very strange reason the Ubuntu 14.04 server install version 0.4.9.6 of logging, while the Ubuntu 14.04 desktop installs 0.5.1.2. pip has the older version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging was manually installed by `pip` or `easy_install`, but the packages in pip are older, thus I had version 0.4.9.6 installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` while the more recent version was installed along python in `usr/lib/python2.7`. It seems on the server the `dist-package` was earlier in the path but not on the desktop. Anyhow, deleting the older package solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody has faced with the same problem when using python3, it could be resolved by importing `logging.handlers` separately from `logging` like this

```
import logging.handlers
logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler('example.log')
```